# Liferay 6.1 Demo porlet error

Tags: liferay, tomcat7, portlet, liferay-6, demo

I am trying to get some of the demo's working, but have been having problems. I am using Tomcat 7 + MySql. When I try to the jsf2 portlet demo found at: http://repository.portletfaces.org/content/repositories/liferay-releases/com/liferay/faces/demos/jsf2-portlet/3.1.0-rc2/jsf2-portlet-3.1.0-rc2.war my logs (configured for log4j) show it gets registered but is immediately unregistered. I have no idea why and am not seeing any reason in the log. I would appreciate any help.

The log entry in question is: "04:17:55,430 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:470] Unregistering portlets for jsf2-portlet".

Here are the ones leading to the one above.

```
04:17:53,693 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:223] Processing faces-config: [/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,694 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:296] Processing web-app: [/WEB-INF/web.xml]
04:17:53,695 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:306] Processing web-app: [/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml]
04:17:53,699 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:341] Added implicit extension-mapped servlet-mapping for urlPattern=[*.xhtml]
04:17:53,699 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:341] Added implicit extension-mapped servlet-mapping for urlPattern=[*.jsp]
04:17:53,713 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:433] 1 portlet for jsf2-portlet is available for use
04:17:55,418 INFO [PluginPackageUtil:1099] Reading plugin package for jsf2-portlet
04:17:55,430 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:470] Unregistering portlets for jsf2-portlet
**04:17:55,437 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:503] 1 portlet for jsf2-portlet was unregistered**
```

The full log can be seen below.:

```
04:17:53,183 INFO [PluginPackageUtil:1099] Reading plugin package for jsf2-portlet
04:17:53,469 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:614] Registering portlets for jsf2-portlet
04:17:53,511 INFO [BridgeImpl] Initializing Liferay Faces Bridge 3.1.0-rc2 (Galatia / Jul 14, 2012 AD)
04:17:53,592 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:168] Pre-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/weld-servlet.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,598 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:168] Pre-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/ext/resin.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,599 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:168] Pre-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/jsf2-portlet/WEB-INF/lib/liferay-faces-alloy-3.1.0-rc2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,600 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:168] Pre-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/jsf2-portlet/WEB-INF/lib/liferay-faces-bridge-impl-3.1.0-rc2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,601 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:168] Pre-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/jsf2-portlet/WEB-INF/lib/util-taglib.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,602 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:202] Post-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/jsf2-portlet/WEB-INF/lib/liferay-faces-bridge-impl-3.1.0-rc2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,603 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:802] render-response-wrapper-class=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.view.BridgeWriteBehindResponseRenderImpl]
04:17:53,604 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:806] resource-response-wrapper-class=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.view.BridgeWriteBehindResponseResourceImpl]
04:17:53,609 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,609 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:592] Instantiated bridgeContextFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.context.BridgeContextFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,615 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,622 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:612] Instantiated bridgeFlashFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.context.flash.BridgeFlashFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,624 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,624 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:632] Instantiated bridgePhaseFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,626 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,663 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:652] Instantiated BridgeRequestScopeFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.scope.BridgeRequestScopeFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,665 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,666 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:673] Instantiated BridgeRequestScopeCacheFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.scope.BridgeRequestScopeCacheFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,668 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,669 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:695] Instantiated BridgeRequestScopeManagerFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.scope.BridgeRequestScopeManagerFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,671 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,672 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:717] Instantiated BridgeWriteBehindResponseFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.view.BridgeWriteBehindResponseFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,676 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,677 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:737] Instantiated BridgeURLFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.context.url.BridgeURLFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,683 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,684 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:789] Instantiated PortletContainerFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.container.PortletContainerFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,686 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:39] Creating instance with zero-arg constructor since wrapperConstructor=null
04:17:53,687 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:817] Instantiated UploadedFileFactory=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.model.UploadedFileFactoryImpl] wrappedFactory=[null]
04:17:53,688 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:202] Post-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/weld-servlet.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,690 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:202] Post-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/ext/resin.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,691 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:202] Post-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/jsf2-portlet/WEB-INF/lib/liferay-faces-alloy-3.1.0-rc2.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,692 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:202] Post-processing faces-config: [jar:file:/usr/local/LiferayTomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/jsf2-portlet/WEB-INF/lib/util-taglib.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,693 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:223] Processing faces-config: [/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml]
04:17:53,694 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:296] Processing web-app: [/WEB-INF/web.xml]
04:17:53,695 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:306] Processing web-app: [/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml]
04:17:53,699 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:341] Added implicit extension-mapped servlet-mapping for urlPattern=[*.xhtml]
04:17:53,699 DEBUG [BridgeConfigImpl:341] Added implicit extension-mapped servlet-mapping for urlPattern=[*.jsp]
04:17:53,713 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:433] 1 portlet for jsf2-portlet is available for use
04:17:55,418 INFO [PluginPackageUtil:1099] Reading plugin package for jsf2-portlet
04:17:55,430 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:470] Unregistering portlets for jsf2-portlet
**04:17:55,437 INFO [PortletHotDeployListener:503] 1 portlet for jsf2-portlet was unregistered**
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe usually means that there's still an exception that occurs, it just isn't being logged correctly by Liferay. What works for me most of the times is to add a logging.properties file to the WEB-INF/classes directory of my portlet and give it the following content:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

After deploying this new WAR you should hopefully see additional logging that should help you find the cause of the failed deployment.